# Paypal pay later

Tags: paypal, payment

I am working on small project where we would like buyer to commit for the payment but dont make a payment now. User is committing for the payment so we can deduct money from user's account in future. There could be delay of days in between user commit to pay and actual payment happen.

Also we would like to make sure that when we will be ready to deduct money from the user, we do get money from user's account. So basically want user to pre-commit for that payment.

Anyone have any idea how to do that with paypal?

We have ruled out the option of paying now and refund later on as it is not suitable.

Comment: Why don't you go and ask Paypal directly? This has nothing to do with programming...

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I was not able to find something over the internet where to ask, and I am a programmer so I thought, I might get some help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look up "preapproved payments" https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/